# Can't skip iCloud setup on iOS 8

Tags: iphone, icloud, ios

I've just downloaded iOS 8 but when it's asking me to set it up it won't let me skip setting up iCloud and it just resets itself! How can I skip this and set up the device?

Comment: There are several steps related to iCloud once your phone boots up in iOS8: Log in into iCloud with your iCloud account/password, set up/enabe iCloud Drive, enable Familiy Sharing. Which of these seems to be unskippable? Can you take a picture of the screen and attach it to the question?

Comment: I don't use icloud, as I back everything up to my laptop. I set iCloud up a couple of years ago, but I changed my email address and I thought I'd changed my e-mail on iCloud but when I go to sign in it still has my old e-mail address and I can't log into that account to verify any changes. I want to skip the iCloud set up so that I'd be able to change it but it keeps resetting itself and its really frustrating because I can't use my phone at all now

Comment: Isn't there an option to create a new iCloud account? You may have to add one anyway for Activation Lock to work correctly.

Comment: No because you need to confirm your password with your old email address and it won't work. So does somebody know a solution? thanks

Comment: Sounds like you had iCloud setup before, and it now needs to confirm those details.  You may not have used it for much, but likely the find my iPhone feature, which is now mandatory on iOS8.  If you can't recall your password, you can reset it